# Normal select query is taking more time

Tags: sql-server

I've attended one interview today. Interviewer asked me that there is one table called "Research". This table is having only 10 records.

Now when i am querying table 
select * from Research 
Its taking little longer time around 20 Secs.

What could be the reason?

I could not imagine this how a table can take this much time if its having only 10 records.

Comment: **Blocking** /enormously slow IO subsystem :)/other transactions pending/very slow network connection...

Comment: I could not get it clear. Could you write in detail. there is no pending transaction.

Comment: This is the same as blocking. Imagine that some other query gets exclusive lock on `Research` table (for instance updating data). In read commited isolation level you cannot read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit obscure and depending on what they are hiring for, not a good one.  My guess is that this question was to feel you out to see what you would do in the situation.  Often very specific questions like these come from issues they have personally experienced.  There are many things that can cause this.  I'd ask, has it always been this way?  Are other tables having the same issue?  Throw it back at them.  Question the system build, location of the DB and I/O.  If OTJ and this just started, my first check would be to make sure they're not running out of disk space.  Mainly because this is common and if not caught more things will be go wrong real soon, if they aren't already.  Second is check the level of fragmentation of the table using DBCC SHOWCONTIG (Table_Name).  If there are some scary #'s here ( common on tables that are heaps ), an easy solution is to drop and re-create the table.

Answer (score 0):

This can have numerous reasons:

On the one hand side, "only 10 records" might be a bit misleading: if each of These records has several nvarchar(max) columns, this might take some time. Furthermore, if the table has like 100 columns, this will take longer as well. Further aspects might be calculated members and so on. Last but not least, if you fire the query over a VPN, this will be significantly slower...

This said: if you could provide some more info on structure, Content, Server, Connection, etc., this would help a lot to narrow down your Problem.

Comment: Even i don't have much information about it. This was a interview question.